# Find element in shadow DOM for python selenium when return arguments[0].shadowRoot doesn't seem viable

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

I'm trying to click the accept cookies button in a python selenium session but it's inside a shadow DOM. Here is an outline of my code:

```
# Python version 3.10.9
# selenium version 3.141.0

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep

url = "https://www.cottages.com/search?adult=2&child=0&infant=0&pets=0&range=3&nights=7&accommodationType=cottages&start=29-12-2023&page=1&sort=priceasc&regionId=21996&regionName=South+West+England"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:/xxx/chromedriver-win64/chromedriver.exe")

driver.get(url)
sleep(5)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
host = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[7]")
root = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", host)
root.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME , 'sc-dcJsrY jLOXfK').click()
```

This returned an AttributeError that dict has no attribute 'find_element'.

I had seen the approach elsewhere on here (e.g. [How to handle elements inside Shadow DOM from Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37384458/how-to-handle-elements-inside-shadow-dom-from-selenium) ) which is why I tried it.

When I printed `root`, I saw that it was just the following dictionary:

```
{'shadow-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '92E369CF463093341CE4281E8449D891_element_93'}
```

Any ideas as to how to access this element to click it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait at least for presence of `shadow host`.
Not sure why are you getting error `AttributeError` - I get error that element with locator `sc-dcJsrY jLOXfK` hasn't been found with your code.

However, this is general consent element and it can be accepted by code below:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
timeout = 10
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)

def get_shadow_root(element):
    return driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', element)

driver.get("https://www.cottages.com/search?adult=2&child=0&infant=0&pets=0&range=3&nights=7&accommodationType=cottages&start=29-12-2023&page=1&sort=priceasc&regionId=21996&regionName=South+West+England")
driver.maximize_window()

shadow_host = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'usercentrics-root')))
shadow_container = get_shadow_root(shadow_host).find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid=uc-app-container]')
WebDriverWait(shadow_container, timeout).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid=uc-accept-all-button]'))).click()
wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'usercentrics-root')))
```

as an alternative approach you can get internal element via JS

```py
shadow_container = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('[data-testid=uc-app-container]')", shadow_host)
```

[Another question with this consent component reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77663676/web-element-button-not-found-by-selenium-python/77668541#77668541)

Comment: Thank you, but even with your code, I get an attribute error. Full error: ```shadow_container = get_shadow_root(shadow_host).find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-testid=uc-app-container]')

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'find_element'```

Comment: @DeeG can you update Chromedriver to latest one?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69582816/python-selenium-attributeerror-dict-object-has-no-attribute-get-attribute

Comment: It shouldn't act in such way, it is for sure mismatch of Selenium version + Chromedriver version

Comment: Have updated chrome and the chrome driver to latest versions and still have the same problem. I also have the same selenium version as suggested in the most upvoted solution in the link you shared

Comment: How about shadow_container = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('[data-testid=uc-app-container]')", shadow_host) ?

Comment: ```File "C:\xxx\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\cottages\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py", line 505, in _clean_keys_and_objs
    raise ValueError("No objects to concatenate")

ValueError: No objects to concatenate```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256343/discussion-between-yaroslavm-and-dee-g).

Comment: The ```shadow_container = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('[data-testid=uc-app-container]')", shadow_host)``` suggestion solved the problem